# Only part of y axis and no x-axis being displayed d3.js

Tags: html, d3.js

I am trying to create a bar chart and in the process I am trying to define the x and y axis. However, I could only see the part of the y-axis and the x-axis seems to be invisible. COuld you please point out as to where I could have gone wrong ?

```
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Bar Chart</title>
    <script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v5.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
    <div id="barchart"></div>
    <script>
        var width = 600;
        var height = 500;
        var margin = 20;

        var svg = d3.select("#barchart").append("svg")
            .attr("width", width-margin)
            .attr("height", height-margin);


        var xScale = d3.scaleBand().range([0, width]).padding(0.1);
        var yScale = d3.scaleLinear().range([height, 0]);

        var g = svg.append("g")
            .attr("transform", "translate(" + 100 + "," + 100 + ")");

        var data1 = { "2011": 9, "2012": 12, "2013": 10, "2014": 8, "2015": 12 }
        data_ready = d3.entries(data1);

        xScale.domain(data_ready.map((function (d) { return d.key; })))
        yScale.domain([0, d3.max(data_ready, function (d) { return d.value; })])

        g.append("g")
            .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
            .call(d3.axisBottom(xScale));

        g.append("g")
            .call(d3.axisLeft(yScale))



    </script>
</body>
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You have some problems with margins and traslate.
Take a look a [this codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/condescending-sunset-oqtfg?file=/index.html), it doesn't solve completely you problem but I think is a good starting point.

The red box is created only to visualize the svg dimensions.

I suggest you to inspect the DOM to see what it's happening :)